# Iteration in TCL using for each

Tags: for-loop, unix, set, tcl

I'm trying to iterate the value using for each in TCL

This how i give input

```
./a.sh value1,value2
```

in the a.sh script

```
set var [lindex $argv 0]
set values [split $var ","]

foreach {set i 0} {$values} {
    puts "iterated once $i"
}
```

i want the iteration to happen twice since there are two values passed . but instead it is iterating only once

please help me on this

thanks in advance

Comment: ".sh" is a misleading extension for a Tcl script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` command, in its simplest form, takes a variable *name*, a list *value*, and a *script* to run for each element of the list. What you were passing was… weird in several ways at once. Look, here's a correct way of doing it:

```
set values [split $var ","]

foreach item $values {
    puts "iterated: $item"
}
```

If you want to count through, you should set up your own counter:

```
set values [split $var ","]

foreach item $values {
    set i [incr counter]
    puts "iterated #$i: $item"
}
```

---

That can be shortened to this:

```
foreach item [split $var ","] {
    puts "iterated #[incr counter]: $item"
}
```

Comment: Alternately, `for` can be used, it's a bit more verbose: `for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $var]} {incr i} {puts "iteration [expr {$i + 1}], value [lindex $var $i]"}`